# Run progress Dialog in Asnyctask while process running

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I am trying to run the following code but I want to show a progress dialog while my process is being run:

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    cm = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    progress_thread = new progress_thread();
    progress_thread.execute();

    isconnected = false;
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
        try{
            URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
            HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
            urlc.connect();
            if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200)  isconnected = true;

        }catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    progress_thread.cancel(true);
    if (!isconnected) Toast.makeText(mContext,"Internet Connexion Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return isconnected;
```

```
private class progress_thread extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean>{

    protected void onPreExecute() { 

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext); 
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading Tracker...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected void onCancelled() {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) dialog.dismiss();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result_ex) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

What I want to do is run the progress dialog while I'm checking if there is internet connection or not. But I am having the problem that the UI is not refreshed and the progress dialog is not shown like i would like.

Comment: why not put `isOnline()` code inside `doInBackground()` method?

Comment: Because I want to call some method run in serial. I want to check if there is Internet Connection (showing a progressdialog while its being checked). Then I want to get location (showing as well a progress dialog). So if I put isONline Mehtod inside the asynctask, the location could be acquired wihtout checking if there is Internet Connection.

Comment: let me re-phrase and explain my question: why not put all your background processing inside `doInBackground()` method? A `Thread.Sleep()` or any other time-based mehtod is certainly not the way to do it.

Comment: Where is your `onProgressUpdate()` method?

Answer (score 0):

The way you do it makes the UI thread occupied by checking for internet connection. This makes the window manager unable to process showing of your `ProgressDialog`.

You should move this check, along with showing progress dialog, to the `AsyncTask`, like so:

```
private void startOnlineCheck() {
    ProgressThread progress_thread = new ProgressThread();
    progress_thread.execute();
}

private class ProgressThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    protected void onPreExecute() { 
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(Activity.this); 
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading Tracker...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) Activity.this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
            try{
                URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                urlc.connect();
                // CODE to run when we're online
                return null;
            }catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Internet Connexion Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // CODE to run when there's no connection
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

You can also pass a `Context` in constructor to `ProgressThread`.

Remember that if `ProgressThread` is an inner class of `Activity` (which is often the case) you can call any method of that activity from any method of `ProgressThread`.

Comment: The problem I have with this code is that if I want to call a method that sent and email after that, I have the problem that maybe internect connection have not been checked before calling the method. So I would like to make the main thread to wait until this finished.

Comment: I don't understand... Can't you save the results of checking for connection somewhere? A variable in Activity maybe? I mean, this *is* the way to do it - you *should not* occupy UI thread with a task that can take more that few hundred milliseconds (and checking for connection is one of them).

Comment: When I click a button the connection status is checked and after that if there's internet connection a mail is sent. But the first time I click the button I get an incorrect value of connected (false) because the thread has not finished yet. What I would like to do is make the main thread to wait until internet-connection thread finishes (and showing a progress dialog while its running)

Comment: A standard way is to run a task, and then run another one. You can easily chain them since `AsyncTask` can have any parameters. Specifically it can take a parameter which is a next task to execute after this one is finished.

Comment: Just to make it clear: you *can't* make the main thread wait. This is because Android application as a whole depends on it's constant processing of messages, events, etc. When you try sleeping the thread for a couple of seconds, Android will send you InterruptedException. When you ignore it, Android will show application not responding error (often called ANR).

Comment: What I wanted to was to call several methos (in other classes) and then this methods were executed in serial, one after other, without having to call them inside the PostExecute method from before. But I see its impossible. So the best way will be to call the next method inside the PostExecute of the metod before it. Isn't it?

Comment: Hm... can't you just call all the methods serially, in one `AsyncTask`'s `doInBackground()`? If you want to update the UI in the middle, you can always do so using `Activity.runOnUiThread()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will do a mix of your answer and your idea, because I want to show a diferent text in the dialogprogress for every method. But any case I can I will try to put all the methods inside the doInBackground.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with the implementation :)